# mongodb find by array specified index and create index for this usage

Tags: mongodb

There is a document

```
{i:[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

and need to find by array element value with specified index:

```
find({ $and: [ {"i.0": 1}, {"i.1": 2} ] })
```

However, this can not take vantadge of index of `createIndex({i:1})`
This kind index seems only work for elemMatch like:

```
find({ i: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } } })
```

Does there have anyways to create index which useful in finding specified index of array like `"i.n"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an index on the fields like you query them.

For example, the index

```
createIndex({"i.0":1, "i.1":1})
```

would do a good job of servicing the query

```
find({ $and: [ {"i.0": 1}, {"i.1": 2} ] })
```

Comment: As a support link, here is the explain plan in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJK8nO_-I_2)

Comment: I think simple `find({ "i.0": 1, "i.1": 2 })` should also work

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit definitely will, the top-level `$and` is included implicitly if you don't specify it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $and: [
               { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$i", 0] }, 1] },
               { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$i", 1] }, 2] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-NvhAAWY2M0)

Comment: I have tested this, no speed up compare to find({ $and: [ {"i.0": 1}, {"i.1": 2} ] }). In constract, find({ i: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } } }) is 10x faster than them

Comment: It depends how flexible/dynamic your query needs to be. For static search you can simply use `{"i.0": 1, "i.1": 2}` and create an index for it.